# How to wire chassis fans to controller

Tags: fan, computer-building, case

This is my first build and i'm using a case with 7 built-in fans. I want to wire them to a controller, but they all have LED's.There is also a button on the case that shuts off the LED's as well as reduces the fan speeds, but I'd rather adjust the speeds through the controller. Can I do that while still keeping the LEDs wired to the shutoff button?
And is there any way I can wire those to a controller as well?

Comment: There are several different wiring specs for PC case fans, 2, 3 and 4 pins. Even within the same number of conductors, some are PWM controlled and some are voltage controlled, some provide an RPM signal and some do not. It would help if you could provide us the fan model numbers, the number of conductors, and what the current controller/switch configuration looks like. If this is a factory or aftermarket case configuration, provide that model information as well.